# Including support libraries in Android makefile - ClassnotfoundException

Tags: java, android, makefile, classnotfoundexception, appcompatactivity

I am using complete android build and building a system app. I created the app using Android Studio and it works fine if I build using studio. Then I placed my code in Android tree and compiled apk using Android.mk file and I included all libraries too - dynamically rather than static (app was giving  many errors while I did static linking). But when I put the app in /system/app folder and launch it gives me ClassNotFoundException for MainActivity. 
Another thing I noticed is when I change my mainActivity extends from Activity  rather than AppCompatActivity then ClassNotFoundException is gone (other relevant errors starts to come though which is expected because  I needed AppCompatActivity).

How should I solve this. Here is my  Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) src/android/hardware/fingerprint/IFingerprintServiceReceiver.aidl
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := src/android/hardware/fingerprint/IFingerprintServiceReceiver.aidl

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.recyclerview

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := \
    frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res \
    frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/res \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4 \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \


LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Did u check the location of these libraries? Are they reside in your app?

Comment: yes. They are part of apk. I opened apk as  zip and looked at all .class files, they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Change LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME:= MyApp

to

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME:= com.full_package_name_for_you_app.MyApp

for example

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME:= com.xyz.MyApp